# Windows 10 Version Update using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, updates

Am I faced with such a problem that I need to **update Widows 10 to next build** (for example from 1903 to 1909) using **PowerShell**.

I use next methods:

1)

```
$Updates = Start-WUScan
Install-WUUpdates -Updates $Updates
```

2)

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force 
Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate -Confirm:$False -Force
Get-Package -Name PSWindowsUpdate
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
$WinUpdates=Get-WindowsUpdate -MicrosoftUpdate -Verbose
Install-WindowsUpdate -KBArticleID $WinUpdates.kb -AcceptAll
```

Both of these options work great, they find and install updates. BUT! All these updates are for the current build only. Updates to the transition to the next build are not found.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how to install an update that will allow me to upgrade to the next version of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

using this manual I was able to update the test computer [tutorial](http://woshub.com/pswindowsupdate-module/) to get list of windows updates:

```
Add-WUServiceManager -ServiceID "7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d" -AddServiceFlag 7
Get-WUlist -MicrosoftUpdate
```

But remember in list can be wrong size of updates....
Notice that when installing a build upgrade with PSWindowsUpdate, restart does not yet finalize upgrade. When you have restarted from PowerShell after PSWindowsUpdate has downloaded and installed build upgrade, it is in fact only initialized, not installed.

You must restart once more from Start > Power > Update and restart
Also you can find usefull info [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/76207-update-upgrade-windows-10-using-powershell.html)

Comment: This method shows me the same results as my second method

Answer (score 1):

I found an article about how you can do a feature upgrade with PowerShell:

```
$dir = 'C:\_Windows_FU\packages'
mkdir $dir
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$url = 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=799445'
$file = "$($dir)\Win10Upgrade.exe"
$webClient.DownloadFile($url,$file)
Start-Process -FilePath $file -ArgumentList '/quietinstall /skipeula /auto upgrade /copylogs $dir'
```

---

I couldn't test it. Here is the source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/51104081-4ed7-4fdd-8b12-5d1f5be532ae/windows-10-feature-update-via-cmd-powershell-or-gpo?forum=win10itprogeneral